# How can I hide the clock on the Gnome 3 lock screen

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, clock, configure

I have looked at the dconf/gsettings keys available and cannot find a way to hide the clock on the lock screen.

The clock interferes visually with the background image on my lock screen.

Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome